# TagLib: Box header specified a size of {0} bytes but only {1} bytes left in the file

Tags: c#, taglib, taglib-sharp

I'm using TagLib to read the ID3 data from MP4 and MP3 files. Generally it's working very well but I have one file that won't show the information.

When debugging I see I have a corruption with the reason: `Box header specified a size of {0} bytes but only {1} bytes left in the file`.

Could someone explain what this means and if it's something I can fix? Is the file just corrupt?

The code I am using to read the tag is:

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
{
    var file = File.Create(new StreamFileAbstraction(filePath, fileStream, fileStream));
    var isCorrupt = file.CorruptionReasons != null && file.CorruptionReasons.Any();
    var title = isCorrupt ? Path.GetFileName(filePath) : file.Tag.Title;
    var track = isCorrupt ? 0 : file.Tag.Track;

    //Removed for brevity
}
```

Comment: ^ This shows that in that commit, the code was modified so that if it found that the box header's specified size > size of file, it would completely skip the parsing step and throw an exception. I would suggest not to check for corruption of the file.